# Java program that program CopyFile that copies one file to another

Tags: java

I want to write a program that copies one file to another. I got my program to execute and run but nothing happens! I have no errors to go by so I'm stuck and don't know what to do! It doesn't create the files or copies them into one file.

Here's the command I typed:

`java CopyFile report.txt report.sav`

The program should create another copy of the file report.txt in report.sav. Your program should print the following error message for inappropriate number of input arguments (for e.g., java CopyFile report.txt):

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
   This program copies one file to another.
*/
public class CopyFile
{  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {  
      if (args.length != 2)
      {  
         System.out.println("Usage: java CopyFile fromFile toFile");
         return;
      }
      String source = args[0];

   }
}
```

Comment: [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) and/or [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: Now, does that copy files onto other files or just makes duplicate files?

Comment: @Killer066, try it and see what happens. I'm sure you didn't read the whole tutorial in 2 minutes.

Comment: Read the links, I'm sure they'll help answer that question

Comment: Would I need to input some 'BufferedReaders' in my code?

Answer (score 1):

use this-

Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());

This method you can find in java 7.

Refer to this link for other ways-
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/

Comment: Could you edit my code so I can see how to use it properly? I never used that method before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache IOCommons

```
FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest)
```